# Replace column values in mySQL table with values from a second table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

- I have a table named "ONE" with a column "Names".
- I have a second table called "TWO" with two columns : "Old_Names" and "New_Names".
- I want to replace the "Names" in table "ONE" with the "Old_Names" from table "TWO".
- The values in "Names" are the same as in "Old_Names" in my tables.

I am trying to do that but I get an error on mySQL :

```
update ONE set (ONE.Names=TWO.New_Names)
from ONE 
join TWO on (ONE.Names=TWO.Old_Names);
```

Comment: Did you mean update with join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the update query :

```
update one o
  join two t on ( o.names = t.old_names )
   set O.names = t.new_names;
```

The join clause has to be write at the beginning of the query =>
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f292c

Answer (score 1):

```
update ONE 
join TWO on ONE.Names = TWO.Old_Names
set ONE.Names = TWO.New_Names
```